# Cannot add files, not a git repository

Tags: git

I followed these steps:

1. `$ cd $Home/projects/`
2. `$ git clone https://github.com/someUser/someRepo.git`
3. `$ git add .`

   `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`
4. `$ git commit -m "first commit"`

   `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: Step 2.5: cd someRepo

Comment: Out of interest, what did you expect `git add .` to do?

Comment: You need to be in a git repository. To find out if your current folder is one, you can run `git status` or look for a `.git` dir in your current folder. You can always initalize a git repository anywhere using `git intit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow below steps:

```
step 1 : cd to $Home/projects/
step 2: git clone https://github.com/someUser/someRepo.git
step 3: cd someRepo
step 3: git add .
step 4: git commit -m "first commit"
```

**NOTE:** The first 2 steps is OK in your case. But after that you have to do `cd someRepo` to move to the git repo directory. And there you can add files.

**ERROR:** You are getting error `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` because as per your steps you are in `$Home/projects/` which is not git repository. After cloned `git clone https://github.com/someUser/someRepo.git` it will create a directory called `someRepo` in `$Home/projects/`. So `$Home/projects/someRepo` is a git repository not `$Home/projects/`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to go to your downloaded repository.
Use`cd someRepo` to go into the directory and then add the files.